# Can I get the location of where the clickonce setup was run?

Tags: clickonce

I'm deploying a standalone clickonce application on a cd. Is there a way to get the location of where the clickonce was run from as opposed to the clickonce cache location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
`ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.AbsolutePath`